# How to efficiently test deferred always

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise, qunit

When writing tests for code in a jQuery ajax (or get) [always](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.always/) part or even in bluebird promises [finally](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/finally.html) like this:

```
function doStuff() {
    console.log('stuff done');
}

function someFunction() {
    return $.get('someurl').always(doStuff);
}
```

I always find myself writing (QUnit) tests for this like:

```
QUnit.test("doStuff will be called when someFunction succeeds", function (assert) {
    var deferred = $.Deferred();
    var backup = $.get;
    $.get = function () { return deferred; };

    var doStuffIsCalled = false;
    doStuff = function(){ doStuffIsCalled = true; };

    deferred.resolve({});
    return someFunction().then(function(){
        $.get = backup;
        assert.ok(doStuffIsCalled);
    });
});

QUnit.test("doStuff will be called when someFunction fails", function (assert) {
    var deferred = $.Deferred();
    var backup = $.get;
    $.get = function () { return deferred; };

    var doStuffIsCalled = false;
    doStuff = function(){ doStuffIsCalled = true; };

    deferred.reject(new Error('some error'));
    return someFunction().catch(function(){
        $.get = backup;
        assert.ok(doStuffIsCalled);
    });
});
```

This works, but is somewhat verbose. Is there some more efficient way, preferrably in a single test, to directly test code called in the always part of a deferred?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Sinon.js to mock jQuery ajax (or get) as well as promises in general.

One approach could be:

```
function someFunction() {
    return $.get('/mytest').always(doStuff);
}

function givenFncExecutesAndServerRespondsWith(reponseNumber, contentType, response) {
    server.respondWith("GET", "/mytest", [reponseNumber, contentType, response]);
    someFunction();
    server.respond();
}

module("Testing server responses", {
    setup: function () {
        server = sinon.sandbox.useFakeServer();
        doStuff = sinon.spy();
    },
    teardown: function () {
        server.restore();
    }
});

test("doStuff will be called when someFunction succeeds", function () {
    givenFncExecutesAndServerRespondsWith(200, '', '');
    ok(doStuff.called, "spy called once");
});

test("doStuff will be called when someFunction fails", function () {
    givenFncExecutesAndServerRespondsWith(500, '', '');
    ok(doStuff.called, "spy called once");
});
```

You can play with this code in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8fe7moed/2/). If instead of `always` you used `done` or `fail` for calling the callback, the corresponding test would fail.

The explanation to the code would be as follows:

1. Create a fake server and a spy that will act as the `always` callback.
2. Modify the response number of the server's response according to what we're testing.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks @acontell! That is definitely a much more compact solution than mine. It would be even nicer if this could be done in a single test, but I guess that's not possible, right? You'll always need to check the success and failure path.

Comment: You're welcome, @PhilipBijker! From my point of view, in order to test always, one test would be enough. The reason is, no matter if the promise fails or succeeds, the result will be the same (so one test either way should be enough). However, if we had a done and fail callbacks instead in someFunction, then two tests would be needed and this implementation would be more suitable.